# Excluíndo símbolo da última posição de uma string, de forma otimizada com PHP

Tags: php, string, regex

Gostaria de excluir o último caractere de uma string se este for um símbolo. Sei que poderia fazer de uma forma complexa como a função a seguir:

```
$string = "minha_string_com_simbolo_no_final_";

function excluir($string){
    $simbolos = ["'","\"", "@","#","$","%","&","*", "(",")","-","_","+","=","
    [","]","§","ª","º","{","}","´","`","^","~","?","/",";",":",",",".",",
    ",">","\\","|","¬","¢","£"]; 

    if(array_search(substr($string, -1), $simbolos)){
       return substr_replace($string, '', -1);
    }
}
```

Ou extremamente simples como a solução abaixo com expressão regular:

```
$string = "minha_string_com_simbolo_no_final_";

print preg_replace("/\W$/", "", $string);
```

Qual a opção tem uma melhor performance?

Qual é a forma correta de fazer testes beanckmark no PHP quando nos deparamos com esses casos?

Comment: Não são equivalentes as duas funções apresentadas na pergunta. Seria bom esclarecer as "regras" da remoção  com mais exatidão para que seja possível uma resposta satisfatória. Se colocar na postagem qual é o problema real a ser resolvido, pode ser mais interessante ainda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a segunda opção é mais otimizada.

```
$string = "minha_string_com_simbolo_no_final_";
print preg_replace("/\W$/", "", $string);
```

Por se tratar de uma expressão regular que tem por finalidade provêr uma forma concisa e flexível de identificar cadeias de caracteres de interesse.
Uma expressão regular é feita para identificar padrões então optaria pela segunda opção.
Nessa referência tem alguns motivos para usar e abusar das expressões:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/10-reasons-to-learn-and-use-regular-expressions

Caso você queira fazer testes de performance você pode dar uma olhada no [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/index.php?action=profiler).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sempre ouvi falar que expressões regulares são mais lentas e devem ser evitadas em situações simples. Neste caso fiquei na dúvida pois a solução com funções de string possui um nível de complexidade muito grande (verificação em um array) mas, mesmo assim poderia ser mais rápida, já a solução com expressão regular é simples (apenas uma linha) mas poderia ter uma execução mais lenta. É difícil saber até que ponto compensa abdicar da performance pela simplicidade e vice-versa.